# when I plot a graph using matplotlib how do I increase the linewidth ( or make bold) one of the lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got a time series which has got many columns. The time series is inthe dataframe called cum_returns. so I am currently plotting all graphs using `cum_returns.plot()`

lets say if I want to make the graph for columns A, C and F darker (or rather increase the line width for those 3 time series) is there an easy way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using the command: `cum_returns.plot()` to plot everything, you can access each of the lines on the plot using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lines = plt.gca().lines
```

then, find out which line you want to edit, i.e. col 'A' is `lines[0]`, 'B' is `lines[1]`..etc..

then change the linewidth using:

```
lines[x].set_linewidth(width) #x is the index of the line you want to edit, width is the new width
```

you can also do dir(lines[x]) to get a full list of the things you can do to it

Comment: thanks @Derek Eden, it seems to be working in my console but not in main program when I run it. I am assuming that this piece of code should work ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lines = plt.gca().lines
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
lines[1].set_linewidth(4)
df.plot()
plt.show()```.  I get an error 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: no you have to plot the data before running plt.gca().lines, otherwise it will return nothing because no lines exist